# CSS change div order without flex

Tags: html, css

given a HTML of:

```
<div class="class">1</div>
<div class="class">2</div>
<div class="class">3</div>
<div class="class">4</div>
```

I know I can do a `display:flex`together with:

```
.class :nth-child(1) { order: 2 }
.class :nth-child(2) { order: 4 }
.class :nth-child(3) { order: 1 }
.class :nth-child(4) { order: 3 }
```

which should produce

```
<div class="class">3</div>
<div class="class">1</div>
<div class="class">4</div>
<div class="class">2</div>
```

Is there a way to do this without using the flexbox in combination with its order property?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not `flexbox`?

Comment: Just a thought of mine how to do this without flex:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use grid layout, which has similar order properties.

```css
.boxes {
  display: grid;
}

.class:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: 2;
}

.class:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 4;
}

.class:nth-of-type(3) {
  order: 1;
}

.class:nth-of-type(4) {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
  <div class="class">1</div>
  <div class="class">2</div>
  <div class="class">3</div>
  <div class="class">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a great answer for me, I had display flex for a 2 column layout, I simply wanted to make the left column show at the bottom when viewport was less than 768px. With flex I was unable to do this simply using order, however with display:grid on the parent this worked beautifully!

Comment: You can also use flex-direction: column-reverse in a situation like mine

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities. The sanest, of course, is to use flex, but if you don't want that, one way is to do it like this.

```css
.container {display: table;}
.class {display: table-row;}
.class:nth-child(3) {display: table-header-group;}
.class:nth-child(2) {display: table-footer-group;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="class">1</div>
  <div class="class">2</div>
  <div class="class">3</div>
  <div class="class">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left` and `float: left;`

```
.class {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
   }

  .class:nth-child(1) {
    left: 75%;
  }

  .class:nth-child(2) {
    left: 25%;
  }

  .class:nth-child(3) {
    left: -25%;
  }

  .class:nth-child(4) {
    left: -75%;
  }
```

Comment: `left` has nothing to do with `float`.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly a more "class"y solution closer to the ":root" of the problem.
With :root variables and css classes utilizing calc.
Chrome, FF and Edge were happy with this.
Use your own .reverse class switcher.

```
    <style>
:root{
/* To Reverse the node order */
  --reverse-order:-1;

/* One for each node */
  --order-1:1;
  --order-2:2;
  --order-3:3;
  --order-4:4;
  --order-5:5;
  --order-6:6;
  --order-7:7;
  --order-8:8;
  --order-9:9;
}
.grid{
    display:grid;
    padding:1em;
    max-width:44em;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,10em);
    gap:1em;
    outline:1px solid black;
}    
.FIELDS{
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}    
.FIELDS *{
    transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}

.order-1{ order:var(--order-1);}
.order-2{ order:var(--order-2);}
.order-3{ order:var(--order-3);}
.order-4{ order:var(--order-4);}
.order-5{ order:var(--order-5);}
.order-6{ order:var(--order-6);}
.order-7{ order:var(--order-7);}
.order-8{ order:var(--order-8);}
.order-9{ order:var(--order-9);}

.reverse .order-1{ order:calc( var(--reverse-order) * var(--order-1) );}
.reverse .order-2{ order:calc( var(--reverse-order) * var(--order-2) );}
.reverse .order-3{ order:calc( var(--reverse-order) * var(--order-3) );}
.reverse .order-4{ order:calc( var(--reverse-order) * var(--order-4) );}
.reverse .order-5{ order:calc( var(--reverse-order) * var(--order-5) );}
.reverse .order-6{ order:calc( var(--reverse-order) * var(--order-6) );}
.reverse .order-7{ order:calc( var(--reverse-order) * var(--order-7) );}
.reverse .order-8{ order:calc( var(--reverse-order) * var(--order-8) );}
.reverse .order-9{ order:calc( var(--reverse-order) * var(--order-9) );}
</style>

<div>
<h4>Fields<button onclick="document.querySelector('.FIELDS').classList.toggle('reverse')">Toggle Order</button></h4>
<div class="grid FIELDS">
  <div class="FIELD order-1 ">Field #1</div>
  <div class="FIELD order-2 ">Field #2</div>
  <div class="FIELD order-3 ">Field #3</div>
  <div class="FIELD order-4 ">Field #4</div>
  <div class="FIELD order-5 ">Field #5</div>
  <div class="FIELD order-6 ">Field #6</div>
  <div class="FIELD order-7 ">Field #7</div>
  <div class="FIELD order-8 ">Field #8</div>
  <div class="FIELD order-9 ">Field #9</div>
</div>
```