# how to Disable Alphabetically Sorting of Labels in post header - blogger

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

I want to control the order of Labels in post header
.
Sorting  Alphabetically is  Not practical In my case 
.
Note :  I do not mean Labels gadget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
.post-labels  {
  display: flex;
}

.post-labels a:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: 2;
}

.post-labels a:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 4;
}

.post-labels a:nth-of-type(3) {
  order: 1;
}

.post-labels a:nth-of-type(4) {
  order: 3;
}
```

It's only CSS, wich it's always a good thing when we must change something in Blogger.

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944457/3992860