# change order of divs without using grid or flex

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am building a news blog *without* the use of `grid` or `flexbox`.

My function uses `Heredoc` in PHP and prints 6 news stories to a page in a sequence from oldest at the top to newest at the bottom like this.

[image]

Problem: Essentially I want to change the div order so that the newest stories IE positions 6,5,4 on the image are **always** delimited on the top line. I have tried to doctor my CSS with `class:nth-of-type(1)` approach as seen in this other stack post without success.

[Here is very similar problem on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943839/css-change-div-order-without-flex)

But can't seem to get this done and wondered if this will need a `JavaScript` solution or can this still be done is `CSS`.

> My Function

```
function get_stories() {


$query = query(" SELECT * FROM stories");
confirm($query);  

while ($row = fetch_array($query)) {

$product_image = display_image($row['story_image']);    


$story = <<<DELIMETER


    <article class="news-item" data-category="Cat">


        <div class="thumb">
           <img src="../resources/{$product_image}" class="headline-story" alt=“wirgo news headline" width=“250" height=“250"></a>               
        </div>


        <div class="news-txt">
            <h3>{$row['story_title']}</h3>
            <p>{$row['story_description']}</p>
        </div>



    </article>






DELIMETER;

echo $story;


}



}
```

> CSS

```
.news-item { 

    display:inline-block !important; 
    vertical-align:top !important; 
    width:403px;
    margin-right:20px !important;
    padding-bottom: 100px !important;
    padding-top: 100px;

}
```

Comment: Have you deployed your code on any server ? Thanks

Comment: are you looking something like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox_flex-wrap_wrap)?

Comment: Not really clear what you mean by delimited or exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your `fetch_array ($query)` in a `array_reverse()`:

```
while ($row = array_reverse( fetch_array($query) ) )
```

That will return the results in the reverse order and will give you what you want. No need for CSS or JS.

Comment: Interesting solution. I appreciate the steering. I will try this shortly. Thanks