# How to move div element using css?

Tags: html, css

I am in the middle of assignment. I am trying to make https://joseff-regmi.github.io/Tutangle/ responsive, I am having trouble with the body part
and most of the css3 features (flex..) are not allowed. how can I stack middle box on the top and followed by left and right on mobile version[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

on mobile:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M80Co.png

Comment: So you want to swap the first two div??

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943839/css-change-div-order-without-flex

Comment: yes! it's kinda like that!

Comment: by the way I can't use flexbox!.

Comment: Being unable to use flex box layout is relevant information that should be in the question (comments are transitory, and prone to deletion). But, may I ask why you're unable to use a simple means of layout that compatible with almost every browser on the market?

Comment: It's a part of assignment and most of the css3 features are not allowed !!

Comment: Then add that to the question, where it can be easily seen, read and understood by those wanting to help you. As I mention elsewhere, though, as it's an assignment you should have made a good effort at solving this problem yourself, so can you show your effort(s)?

Comment: If you can't use flexbox you can use position absolute... but it isn't a good solution? what have you tried?

Comment: https://joseff-regmi.github.io/Tutangle . I am making this site responsive .If you look at ...I wanted entries part on the top  instead of research result. On mobile version!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and its [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property :

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#child1 {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  order: 2;
}

#child2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  order: 1;
}

#child3 {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <label for="">This is parent</label>
    <div class="child" id="child1">This is child1</div>
    <div class="child" id="child2">This is child2</div>
    <div class="child" id="child3">This is child3</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Actually I am not allowed to use flex box, it's an assignment so !!

Comment: @Govinda: then perhaps that should have been in the question, rather than added to comments that invalidate answers made in good effort to help you? Are there any other restrictions you're required to operate under? And, as this is an assignment, you should be able to solve, or at least understand, the problem well enough to have made an effort yourself. So, please: can you share your own best attempt? And no, your CSS showing you've assigned colours isn't a best effort at solving a layout problem.

Comment: @GovindaRegmi there is an alternative solution using `display: grid`, but before I update my answer... are you allowed to use this CSS rule ??

Comment: I am updating question !!!

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use flexbox, then this is a way to get your work done

show/hide desktop and mobile div based on needs using media query,

for example: `display:block;` for class `desktop`,
and `display:none;` for class `mobile` and vice-versa

```
<div class="parent desktop">
  <label for="">This is parent</label>
  <div class="child" id="child1">This is child1</div>
  <div class="child" id="child2">This is child2</div>
  <div class="child" id="child3">This is child3</div>
</div>
<div class="parent mobile">
  <label for="">This is parent</label>
  <div class="child" id="child2">This is child2</div>
  <div class="child" id="child1">This is child1</div>
  <div class="child" id="child3">This is child3</div>
</div>
```